# navigation images to be transparent while the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to make navigation bar images (home, news, about etc) in such a way that, when the page loads, it be transparent on load, and when we hover mouse over it , its opacity would become 100%, like J-Query fades method & and on hover out it would becomes transparent, but J-Query this method is inverted... i tried J-Query fades method but when the page loads, they are already with 100% opacity, how can i code this !
thanks

i tried this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".navfade").mouseover(function(){
         $(this).fadeTo(500,1)
         });
         });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navfade").mouseout(function(){
      $(this).fadeTo(500,0.65)
       });
        });

</script>
```

but its not what i want

Comment: Can you try to get an example case set up in JSfiddle with your HTML layout and your CSS, etc?

Comment: Also, you do not need two ready functions to do what you are looking to do.

Comment: Please, there is no need for jQuery or javascript. Ever heard of Cascading Style Sheets? Style your elements with the desired opacity and use `:hover`. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$(function() {
    $(".navfade").css({opacity: 0.5});
    $( ".navfade" ).hover(
      function() {
        $( this ).animate({opacity: 1});
      }, function() {
        $( this ).animate({opacity: 0.5});
      }
    );  
});
```

Comment: You could also set the .navfade initially in your CSS instead of in the ready function.  Probably preferred that way unless you need to set it initially via JS for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* CSS */ 
       .navfade {
            opacity: 0.5;
            -moz-opacity:0.5;
            -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
            -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        }

/* JS */

    $(function() {
        $('.navdfade').hover(

            function() {
                $(this).animate({opacity : 1.0}, 250);
            },
            function() {
                $(this).animate({opacity : 0.5}, 250);
            });
    });
```

Adjust the opacity and fade duration to your liking. Enjoy!